# How to deal with comments asking the answerer to have a look at another question

Tags: discussion, comments, linked-questions

I've come across some comments from the OP on some of the answers asking to look at another question. The linked question most likely is not related to the present question.

What would be the appropriate process of dealing with the comment? Since, it doesn't add anything useful to the answer, but is rather a request.

As an example, I flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719060/how-to-get-all-the-li-of-ul-selenium-webdriver/24719064#comment38341445_24719064) as *not constructive*. It was declined.

Comment in question:

> it worked fine. Please have a look on this one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719614/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719614/how-to-make-the-click-work-in-selenium-webdriver)

Was the reason it got declined, because the answerer did not provide an answer to the linked question? It is obvious that such a high-rep user has seen the comment and visited the linked answer, but chose not to answer.

The comment adds some more visibility to the unanswered question at the expense of being off-topic for the answer it is on.

Would the comment be deleted if the linked question was indeed answered?

Comment: Such comments sure beat emails asking for the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the linked question is not related to the current question then flag it with the "other" option. The moderators will see the flag and delete the comment if it truly is irrelevant.

I can't speak for the moderator who declined this flag but it could be that they simply disagreed with you. Comments (as we keep saying) are second class citizens so we don't want to spend too much time dealing with any flags that might be raised on them. If the flag isn't clear what the problem actually is it may well be that we decline it.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense to flag it as *other* to let the moderator know in detail, why this is not an appropriate comment.